# Is there time limit or weight limit when calling "on_finalize()" hook?

Tags: weight, limit

I want to clear a StorageMap in on_finalize()  hook function. The code like this:

```
        //clear current epoch data for the next cycle
        let mut mrr: MultiRemovalResults = <CurrentEpochData<T>>::clear(10000, None);
        loop {
            match mrr.maybe_cursor{
                None => break,
                Some(v) => {
                    mrr = <CurrentEpochData<T>>::clear(10000, Some(&v[..]));
                }
            }
        }
```

The code above is written in on_finalize, and I am not sure if I can do this. I am afraid that there is some limitation with on_finalize hook, such as time limit or weight limit.

Need help！！！

Comment: This is a brilliant resource to understand `weights` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bb0JotmiGEM&t=5s

Answer (score 1):

`on_finalize` is guaranteed to run at the end of a block. A trick is to [move the logic rather to `on_initialize` instead of `on_finalize`](https://substrate-developer-hub.github.io/docs/en/knowledgebase/runtime/benchmarking#minimize-usage-of-on_finalize-and-trasition-logic-to-on_initialize). You could potentially leave it in `on_finalize`, if you know exactly how much weight `on_finalize` takes and add that additional weight to `on_initialize`.

---

I couldn't find [the method `clear` implemented for the `StorageMap` here](https://crates.parity.io/frame_support/pallet_prelude/struct.StorageMap.html). You should probably think about using [`remove_all`](https://crates.parity.io/frame_support/pallet_prelude/struct.StorageMap.html#method.remove_all) or [`drain`](https://crates.parity.io/frame_support/pallet_prelude/struct.StorageMap.html#method.drain) for clearing the `StorageMap`.

In addition to that, I would probably making absolutely sure, that you don't remove (and therefore make a storage write) too many values of the `StorageMap` in one block, because storage writes are expensive. This is the reason, why there is a limit specified for the usage of `remove_all`.

---

Yes, you are absolutely right, that there is a limit of maximal computation ([weight](https://docs.substrate.io/build/tx-weights-fees/)) for each block.

But `on_finalize` can exceed the maximal block limit, because the hook is in the `Mandatory` dispatch class. The drawback of this is a longer block execution time than the expected target block time (like 6 seconds for Kusama). But as long as you count the weights for each action (`on_initialize`, `on_finalize`, `on_runtime_upgrade` and the dispatch functions) correctly, then and only then, the `on_finalize` leads to no overweight in the block.

You can see an example of removing items with a `RemoveKeysLimit` configuration constant [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/f23b88302570f800234bacc6f92153b9433e3429/runtime/common/src/crowdloan/mod.rs#L523-L533). The `remove` doesn't happen on a `StorageMap`, but you should use this principle with [`drain`](https://crates.parity.io/frame_support/pallet_prelude/struct.StorageMap.html#method.drain) accordingly.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: What do you mean in the first para when you say : " add that additional weight to on_initialize." ?

Comment: I meant that you would need to calculate the weight of on_finalize and reserve that beforehand with on_initialize. (So that you have enough space for the execution of on_finalize)

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possibilities here depending on your needs.

- Using a runtime migration when there are large one-time changes to be made.
- Using `on_idle` to lazily do some cleanup. `on_idle` get the remaining weight as argument, so you can calculate how much operations you can do. This is easier to use than a migration IMO.

With `on_initialize` and `on_finalize` you need to be careful not to go overweight, otherwise the block could be rejected by collators if this happens on a para-chain.

EDIT: To actually answer your question from the title:
Yes there is a limit. It is shared with `on_initialize` such that `on_initialize` returns the weight for both `on_initialize` and `on_finalize`.