# Are both of them same StorageMap？

Tags: storage, struct, crates

I found this puzzle in my [last question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4417/is-there-time-limit-or-weight-limit-when-calling-on-finalize-hook), which is from one answer of my question.

There are at least two StorageMap structs in substrate framework.Their links are listed below:

https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/storage/types/struct.StorageMap.html
https://crates.parity.io/frame_support/pallet_prelude/struct.StorageMap.html

They are StroageMap structs with little difference. They have different function sets at first glance. I want to figure out which struct should I pick up when coding a pallet in substrate?

Answer (score 2):

The one that you should use is the [first one](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/storage/types/struct.StorageMap.html). If you take a look at the `pallet_prelude` crate, you can see that the `StorageMap` used across most of the tutorials is being 'imported' from the `storage::types` crate.

```rs
pub use crate::{
        dispatch::{DispatchError, DispatchResult, DispatchResultWithPostInfo, Parameter},
        ensure,
        inherent::{InherentData, InherentIdentifier, ProvideInherent},
        storage,
        storage::{
            bounded_vec::BoundedVec,
            types::{
                CountedStorageMap, Key as NMapKey, OptionQuery, StorageDoubleMap, StorageMap,
        HERE --> StorageNMap, StorageValue, ValueQuery,
            },
        },
        traits::{
            ConstU32, EnsureOrigin, Get, GetDefault, GetStorageVersion, Hooks, IsType,
            PalletInfoAccess, StorageInfoTrait,
        },
        weights::{DispatchClass, Pays, Weight},
        Blake2_128, Blake2_128Concat, Blake2_256, CloneNoBound, DebugNoBound, EqNoBound, Identity,
        PartialEqNoBound, RuntimeDebug, RuntimeDebugNoBound, Twox128, Twox256, Twox64Concat,
    };
```

So basically, when you call `frame_support::pallet_prelude::StorageMap` you are calling the one inside the `storage::types` crate.

As for the question 'why are there two StorageMaps?' I think the second one is used in old versions of FRAME, where you would use `decl_storage` to create your structures. It has to exist because although substrate is being updated constantly, it is backward compatible with old implementations of it. But I'm not 100% sure thats the reason.

Taking a look at the `storage::StorageMap`:

```rs
/// A strongly-typed map in storage.
///
/// Details on implementation can be found at [`generator::StorageMap`].
pub trait StorageMap<K: FullEncode, V: FullCodec> {
...
```

and then the `generator::StorageMap`:

```rs
/// Generator for `StorageMap` used by `decl_storage`.
/// ...

pub trait StorageMap<K: FullEncode, V: FullCodec> {
```

The docs of the implementation state that the generator is used by the `decl_storage` function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

`frame_support::pallet_prelude` re-exports the most common used types and constants for ease of use.
The re-export happens [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/2b54771bf923b1f220b6997e710d7169f3dc613b/frame/support/src/lib.rs#L1370).
It is therefore exactly the same type, as you can discover by clicking on the `src` links.
The crates.io is outdated, that is why it looks a bit different.

Comment: I got it,thank you very much！